# How to prevent contact detail exchange?

Tags: php, marketplace

Is there any algorithm or library (e.g. in PHP) that provides a "phone number exchange prevention"?

Basically e.g. a phone number like

0123 45 67 89

can easily be removed by regular expression.
But a number like

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

can harder be detected. And then even harder, the hardest case:

```
my number is: zero one two three four five six seven
```

How would you remove something like this via PHP regex? Is there a library?

Comment: No. You come up with a regex, someone will come up with a way of bypassing it. "My number is the sum of the year in which America gained independence times a thousand."

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? To prevent a phone number on a web page from being scraped?

Comment: You can't do this without human eyes screening messages or whatever beforehand.

Comment: @tadman agreed, but only partially. You can try specific things at least

Comment: @Hassaan 

$pattern = array(
        "/[0-9.:;,!\/]{12,}/",
        "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/",
        '/\+?[0-9][0-9()\-\s+\/\.]{9,20}[0-9]/'
    );

in terms of regex

Comment: @Mr Glass : People exchanging third parties' phone details with the right to

Comment: There is absolutely no way to prevent humans from being human. No regular expression can stop this. Every effort to do so in the past has failed utterly. See also: [Clbuttic](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-) and "My number is ④①⑥..." or "⁴¹⁶..." or "四㆒六..."